# Issues using @tezos/taquito

Tags: taquito, tezos-signer

I'm getting this error after installing tezos/taquito library in the frontend of my application, this is the error that I get when trying to load my app.

```
  ./node_modules/@vespaiach/axios-fetch-adapter/index.js:2:0
    Module not found: Package path ./lib/core/settle is not exported from package /Users/zerotimedrift/Documents/GitHub/auth/frontend/node_modules/axios (see exports field in /Users/zerotimedrift/Documents/GitHub/auth/frontend/node_modules/axios/package.json)
    
    Import trace for requested module:
    ./node_modules/@taquito/http-utils/dist/taquito-http-utils.es6.js
    ./node_modules/@taquito/taquito/dist/taquito.es6.js
    ./components/accounts.tsx
    ./pages/index.tsx
    
    https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Comment: Can you also post the TypeScript code that generated the error? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`axios-fetch-adapter` is something we use to have fetch-based HTTP requests in our HTTP helpers.

Have you tried removing your `node_modules` and do a clean NPM install?

In an upcoming version 15.1.0 there might be fixes pertaining the `axios-fetch-adapter`, but your error doesn't seem to be related